# É possível inserir ao mesmo input, mas com dois valores diferentes usando Ant.design?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou usando o React + Ant.design e preciso criar uma Table onde cada linha receba o mesmo input, no entanto ele deve ter valores diferentes, o jeito que estou fazendo o segundo valor substitui o primeiro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que os dois valores sejam salvos, mas só esta salvando o último.

Minha Table:

```
<Table dataSource={questions} pagination={false} size="middle">
          <Column
            title="Remuneração"
            width="50%"
            dataIndex="selectOption"
            key="selectOption"
          />

          <Column
            title="Desejado"
            className="text-center"
            render={this.renderInput()}
          />

          <Column
            title="Oferecido"
            className="text-center"
            render={this.renderInput()}
          />
        </Table>
```

RenderInput:

```
renderInput = id => (text, record) => (
    <Input
      name={record.key}
      onChange={this.onInputChange}
    />
  );
```

onInputChange:

```
onInputChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) =>
    this.props.onChange({ ...this.props.value, [name]: value });
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que o resultado seja algo assim:

salario-direto: "first value", "second value"